# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!$

Tags: summation, factorial

I discovered that the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!$ equals $(n+1)!-1$.

But I want a proof. Could anyone give me one please? Don't worry if it uses very advanced math, I can just check it out on the internet. :)

Comment: Are you familiar with mathematical induction?

Comment: @anon Sorry, I'm really not that good in proofs, and I don't know the types of proofs. Could you please help?

Comment: I want to say... THANKS! I finally have enough reputation to vote answers! Well, actually, only to upvote, but I don't think I will be downvoting anytime soon, anyways...

Comment: please don't use titles only containing MathJax, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1204/19341)...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HINT: $k(k!)=(k+1-1)(k!)=(k+1)!-k!$. Now do the summation and most of the terms will cancel.

Comment: Thanks for editing! And also thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 10):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1-1)k!=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((k+1) k!- k!\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n  ((k+1)!-k!)=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)!-\sum_{k=1}^n k!=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)!+(n+1)!-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)!=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)!+(n+1)!-(0+1)!-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)!=$$
$$=(n+1)!-1$$

Comment: Wow. Suppose that math is not always **that** easy to understand...

Comment: This is very elegant, but for the sake of clear presentation I would suggest that line 3 be just changing the second sum to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)!$ and the fourth line be $(n+1)!-(0+1)!$ alone.

Answer (score 3):

By telescoping
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\times k!=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((k+1)\times k!- k!\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n  ((k+1)!-k!)=(n+1)!-1$$

Comment: I am wonder if Leonardo da Vinci didn't invent telescope, what would this series be called!! :D for my sleepy brother.

Comment: @B.S. - In Chinese it's called "Splitting Summation" (rough translation)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit overkill, but I think it's still worth showing:
using that
$$
k!=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^kdt\,,
$$
we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sum_{k=1}^n kt^k dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k=0}^n t^k dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty te^{-t}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}dt
\end{aligned}$$
and integrating by parts yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k! = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}(t^{n+1}-1)dt=(n+1)!-1\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}=(n+1)!-1$.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}{k}\cdot{k!}=(1+1)!-1$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}=(n+1)!-1$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}{k}\cdot{k!}=$
- $\color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k}\cdot{k!}}+{(n+1)}\cdot{(n+1)!}=$
- $\color{red}{(n+1)!-1}+{(n+1)}\cdot{(n+1)!}=$
- $(n+1)!\cdot(n+2)-1=$
- $(n+2)!-1$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 0):

Let the $k^\text{th}$ term of the given series be $T_k$,

$T_k=k \cdot k!=(k+1-1) \cdot k!=(k+1) \cdot k!-k!=(k+1)!-k!$

Put $k=1,T_1=2!-1!$

Put $k=2,T_2=3!-2!$

Put $k=3,T_3=4!-3!$

.

.

.

and so on...

Put $k=n-1, T_{n-1}=n!-(n-1)!$

Put $k=n, T_n=(n+1)!-n!$

Note that $T_1+T_2+T_3+\dots+T_n=(n+1)!-1$ since alternate terms one the RHS's cancel out.

Hope this helps.