# Find the sum $ 1 \cdot 1! + 2 \cdot 2! + 3 \cdot 3! + ... + n \cdot n! $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math, factorial

Find the sum 
$$ 1 \cdot 1! + 2 \cdot 2! + 3 \cdot 3! + ... + n \cdot n!  $$

---

**Attempt**

$$ 2 \cdot 2! + 3 \cdot 3! = 2 \cdot 2! + 3^{2} \cdot 2! = 2! (2+3^{2})$$

$$ 4 \cdot 4! + 5 \cdot 5! = 4 \cdot 4! + 5^{2} \cdot 4! = 4! (4+5^{2})$$

$$ 6 \cdot 6! + 7 \cdot 7! = 6 \cdot 6! + 7^{2} \cdot 6! = 6! (6+7^{2})$$

then 
$$ 2 \cdot 2! + 3 \cdot 3! + 4 \cdot 4! + 5 \cdot 5! + 6 \cdot 6! + 7 \cdot 7!$$
$$ = 2! (2+3^{2}) + 4! (4+5^{2}) + 6! (6+7^{2})$$

or perhaps we can calculate in total, for example

$$  2 \cdot 2!  + 3 \cdot 3! + 4 \cdot 4! + 5 \cdot 5!$$
$$ = 2!(2 + 3^{2}) + 4 \cdot 4! + 5 \cdot 5!= 2!(2 + 3^{2}) + 2! (4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3) + 5 \cdot 5! $$
$$ = 2! (2 + 3^{2} + 3 \cdot 4^{2}) + 2! (4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^{2})$$
$$ = 2! (2 + 3^{2} + 3 \cdot 4^{2} + 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5^{2})$$

Comment: I have added an answer here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410290/evaluate-sum-k-1nk-cdot-k

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$n\cdot n!=(n+1-1)n!=(n+1)!-n!$

Do you know about [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?