# Find the remainder when $(1! \times 1) + (2! \times 2) + (3! \times 3) + \cdots + (100! \times 100)$ is divided by $101$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm faced with a difficult problem that I can't prove.

The problem is stated as:

Find the remainder when $(1! \times 1) + (2! \times 2) + (3! \times 3) + \cdots + (100! \times 100)$ is divided by $101$.

I found a pattern which is $(1! \times 1) + (2! \times 2) + (3! \times 3) + \cdots + (n! \times n)$ is exactly $n$ when in modulus $n + 1$, I couldn't proof it so I need some help, thanks!

Comment: $\sum_{r=1}^n r\cdot r! = \sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)!-r! = (n+1)!-1 \equiv -1 \pmod {n+1}$.

Comment: @DS It does answer my question, thank you so much! You should have make an answer instead of a comment so I can flag your answer as correct 

Comment: No, this is a duplicate, and duplicates should not be answered. Instead, they should be closed with a link to the original question.

Comment: I am not sure how closing as duplicate works, but I think you would have seen a yes/no beside my comment?

Comment: It really is, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since $101$ is a prime no and as it does not appear even once until $100!  . 100$ . So we will divide the sum of the series by $101$ to directly find the remainder. The sum can easily calculate by writing $S_n =\sum n .n!$ Which can be split and written as sigma of $(n+1 -1)×n!$ Which on opening becomes $n+1! - n!$.so taking the sum of the obtained term from $n = 1 \to n=100 $we get the sum as $101!-1$ which on being divided by $101$ gives $-1$ as remainder.  So $-1 +101= 100$ is the remainder.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please [don't answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) duplicate questions. Instead, if you feel your answer is different from the answers to the older question or has a new idea (which is _not_ the case here), post an answer to the [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410290/evaluate-sum-k-1nk-cdot-k).